# Pinterest API create board returns NULL (PHP)

Tags: php, api, curl, pinterest

I am using PHP curl to post to https://api.pinterest.com/v1/boards/?access_token=mysecrettoken

I have two parameters, name and description that are being posted.

```
$data = array( 'name' => 'API Test', 'description' => 'Please ignore just a test' );
```

What I get back from Pinterest is NULL.  It does create the board on Pinterest but I really need to know if it was successful and I need the board id.

What I would expect would be something like below.  Which is what I get when using the API explorer.

```
root:{} 1 item data:{} 3 items url:https://www.pinterest.com/mrnickpowers/api-test/ id:73183631383926646 name:API Test
```

My curl function for posting works with other endpoints.  Anyone have a clue what might be happening here?

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: Hi, Nick, and welcome to Stack Overflow. You have to add some details to obtain a proper answer. Can show the code that fails? How you send the request? Please add any other detail that can help users to locate the problem.

Comment: I found my problem... something stupid.  Sorry for waisting your time.

Comment: @NickPowers Hi Nick, welcome to the internet. Meaning, you found yourself as stupid but yet you continued this stupidity by not posting how you solved it?